# How do I sync my swift --version to my xcrun swift --version?

Tags: swift, swift4

The version of swift Xcode is using is different from the one I have when I run swift --version. Its because I tried to download Swift 4 from swift.org. I want to sync both of them. I can use swiftenv to update the global version but I prefer to use a Apple supported versioning system.

```
xcrun swift -version
Apple Swift version 4.0.3 (swiftlang-900.0.74.1 clang-900.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9


swift --version
Apple Swift version 4.0 (swift-4.0-RELEASE)
```

Comment: `whereis swift` what does it say? I have stock Xcode swift and swift lives in /usr/bin/. Not sure where the swift.org version is installed.

Comment: It gives me /usr/bin/swift

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the command line tool by :
`xcode-select --install`

this should overwrite the current swift version to the default apple one.

Comment: then you could `sudo rm /usr/bin/swift` then `ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift /usr/bin/swift`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [swiftenv](https://swiftenv.fuller.li/en/latest/) tool to manage all the swift versions on your machine. Use the tool to list all the swift versions, and set the global version which you want. 
Good Luck.